# How to Open all minimized File Explorer windows

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, taskbar

Let's say I have Minimized several File Explorers, perhaps by right-clicking an open spot on the taskbar and choosing "Show the Desktop". Now I want to  them all Restored at once. I see no way to Restore them all other than hovering over the taskbar icon and clicking on each window separately.

Any modern version of Windows works like this. I am on Win7 currently.

Basically I would like to add an item to the right-click menu, below "Close all Windows", that says "Open all Windows".

Is there some shortcut I'm missing, or is there a way to add items to the right-click menu? I'm not interested in 3rd party tools, but I can program if someone gives me some clues.

Thanks.

[edit] Windows + D sorta worked. It closes open Windows, and hitting it again restores what it closed. But if you Win+D and then open a program, hitting it again will close that program and only open the same program back up. 
But question was how to open all the **Explorer windows**, in the same manner you can close them all, by right-click on the taskbar icon. I want an Open All option on that menu. 
Essentially, I want to add functionality to the right-click menu.

Comment: windows logo button+shift+M but this question is off-topic and may be better suited for [superuser](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: Logo+shift+M did absolutely nothing discernible on my Win7 machine, or on Server 2012R2. Is it possible you have something mapped to that shortcut?

Comment: Well, works fine for me and it's what's listed in the [documentation](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts#keyboard-shortcuts=windows-7) easily found with a quick trip to a search engine. If you wanted to create a custom shortcut you could [do that](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-keyboard-shortcuts-open-programs#1TC=windows-7) too. Best of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

Press SHIFT, right-click on the group icon and choose Restore all windows

Comment: Is there also a shortcut/quicker way to do this?